# check for existence of an AWS ARN from within an IAM policy and execute actions based upon this

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, single-sign-on, identity-management, aws-policies

I need to to be able to do this "pseudo code" from within an IAM policy

If (ARN exists)
then
Execute actions block on listed resoures
else
Do nothing and continue
fi

My idea.

ARN1 is an SSO permissioon set looking like (say) - listed below. a clean deny on IAM.
arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-77778f8b38f9c920/ps-e29f0cbbb9e35f55

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "NoOpPolicyForAwsSsoEnvAndPrivSettings",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": "IAM:*",
"Resource": "*"
}
]
}

The user logs into  SSO group2 that CAN see ARN1 because they are ALSO in SSO group1 where ARN1 is attached .

WHEN RUNNING this policy section flow what happens with the ec2 actions when

1. ARN1 IS visible
2. ARN1 is NOT visible

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "EC2WithAwssoViewerPermSet",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:DescribeInstances",
"ec2:DescribeImages",
"ec2:DescribeTags",
"ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
"cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
"cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
"iam:ListPolicies"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:ec2:::*",
"arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-77778f8b38f9c920/ps-e29f0cbbb9e35f55"
]
},

```
thanks


Need a thought experiment analysis from  IAM experts ;-)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could do this test in code outside of the policy and generate the appropriate policy based on the condition. For example, using CDK.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to bne able to TEST for the existence of an ARN during IAM policy evalution and then execute based upon its existence. Not via TF or CFN.